# Are calculations involving a large matrix using arrays in VBA faster than doing the same calculation manually in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel, matrix

I am trying to do calculations as part of regression model in Excel.

I need to calculate `((X^T)WX)^(-1)(X^T)WY`. Where `X`, `W`, `Y` are matrices and `^T` and `^-1` are denoting the matrix transpose and inverting operation.

Now when `X`, `W`, `Y` are of small dimensions I simply run my macro which calculates these values very very fast.

However sometimes I am dealing with the case when say, the dimensions of `X`, `W`, `Y` are `5000 X 5`, `5000 X 1` and `5000 X 1` respectively, then the macro can take a lot longer to run.

I have two questions:

1. Would, instead of using my macro which generates the matrices on Excel sheets and then uses Excel formulas like `MMULT` and `MINVERSE` etc. to calculate the output, it be faster for larger dimension matrices if I used arrays in VBA to do all the calculations? (I am not too sure how arrays work in VBA so I don't actually know if it would do anything to excel, and hence if it would be any quicker/less computationally intensive.)
2. If the answer to the above question is no it would be no quicker. Then does anybody have an idea how to speed such calculations up? Or do I need to simply put up with it and wait.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you have to deal a lot with huge matrices then Matlab might be worth a look. It is really strong with huge matrices. It might be a little over powered for your use case (I can't tell because I don't know your exact use case).

Comment: I don't know how to explain it really other than how I did. Sorry.

Comment: I meant it is your decision which tool is suitable to your case. Matlab is a very powerful tool but not as easy to use as Excel. I would only switch if Excel takes a day or more to calculate it.

Comment: It normally takes a few minutes so not to bad and not worth matlab in my opinion. I was thinking about using VBA but I'm not sure if it is worth it. That is if it will take 5 minutes in excel and 4 in VBA then it is not worth it. However if it takes 5 minutes in excel and 30 seconds in VBA then I would try to do VBA, can you comment on the respective time frames with your best guess?

Comment: this highly depends on how your source data looks like. You cannot guess how big your gain in time would be with VBA. You can just code that solution in VBA and measure the time to get the difference. It also depends on your VBA code. If it is good it will be faster if it is bad it might be even slower than Excel. You see: Too many variables to make a good guess.

Comment: Okay got you. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the algorithm of the code is the same, the speed ranking is the following:

1. Dll custom library with C#, C++, C, Java or anything similar
2. VBA
3. Excel

I have compared a [VBA vs C++ function here](https://www.vitoshacademy.com/vba-vs-c-function-which-one-is-faster-in-excel/), in the long term the result is really bad for VBA.

So, the following Fibonacci with recursion in C++:

```
int __stdcall FibWithRecursion(int & x)
{
    int k = 0;
    int p = 0;

    if (x == 0)
        return 0;

    if (x == 1)
        return 1;

    k = x - 1;
    p = x - 2;
    return FibWithRecursion(k) + FibWithRecursion(p);
}
```

is exponentially better, when called in Excel, than the same complexity function in VBA:

```
Public Function FibWithRecursionVBA(ByRef x As Long) As Long

    Dim k As Long: k = 0
    Dim p As Long: p = 0

    If (x = 0) Then FibWithRecursionVBA = 0: Exit Function
    If (x = 1) Then FibWithRecursionVBA = 1: Exit Function

    k = x - 1
    p = x - 2

    FibWithRecursionVBA = FibWithRecursionVBA(k) + FibWithRecursionVBA(p)

End Function
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand are you saying that C++ > VBA > Excel but that VBA and Excel are not too much different? In terms of deal with matrices as specified above would it be worth working in VBA. E.g. If I did the calculations as previously mentioned in VBA vs Excel are we talking about VBA being a few seconds quicker or a few minutes quicker?

Comment: @Tom - VBA is faster than Excel in every scenario. Concerning minutes vs seconds - did it really took you minutes to calculate this `((X^T)WX)^(-1)(X^T)WY` 5000 times in Excel?

Comment: It only calculates that once it is just that the matrices are very big. I am not sure if you are familiar with matrix calculations.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never:
I use matrices that are bigger, 3 or 4 dimensions, sized like 16k x 26 x 5.
I run through them to find data, apply one or two formulas or make combos with other matrices.

Number one, after starting the macro, open another application like notepad, you might have a nice speed increase ☺ !

Then, I guess you switched of screen updating etc, and turned of automatic calculation

As last: don't put the data in cells, not in arrays.
Just something like:

- Dim Matrix1 as String   ===>'put it in declarations if you want to use it in other macros as well. Remember you can not do "blabla=activecell.value2" etc anymore!!
- In the "Sub()" code, use ReDim Matrix1(1 to a_value, 1 to 2nd_value, ... , 1 to last_value)
- Matrix1(45,32,63)="what you want to put there"

After running, just drop the

Matrix1(1 to a_value, 1 to 2nd_value,1) at 1st sheet,

Matrix1(1 to a_value, 1 to 2nd_value,2) at 2nd sheet, etc

Switch on screen updating again, etc
In this way my calculation went from 45 minutes to just one, by avoiding the intermediary screen update
Success, I hope it is useful for somebody